# Redeclaration of Let error - How to find where it's being reassigned?

Tags: javascript, shopify

The console error - "Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let sectionSelector"

The code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const sectionSelector = '#shopify-section-{{ section.id }}';
  
  let collectionSelectors = document.querySelectorAll(`${sectionSelector} .recommendations__collection-selector`);
  
  for (let collectionSelector of collectionSelectors) {
    let blockId = collectionSelector.dataset.blockId;

    let collectionCarousel = document.querySelector(`${sectionSelector} .recommendations__collection[data-block-id="${blockId}"]`);
    let otherCarousels = document.querySelectorAll(`${sectionSelector} .recommendations__collection:not([data-block-id="${blockId}"])`);

    collectionSelector.addEventListener('click', () => {

      for (let otherCarousel of otherCarousels) {
        otherCarousel.classList.remove('active');
      }

      for (let collectionSelector of collectionSelectors) {
        collectionSelector.classList.remove('active');
      }

      collectionSelector.classList.add('active');
      collectionCarousel.classList.add('active');

      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    })
  }
</script>
```

I first changed `let sectionSelector` to `const`, that changes the error to collectionSelectors. This is the only reference to sectionSelector I have on the site, the error persists even if I have a single line -

```
  let sectionSelector = '#shopify-section-{{ section.id }}';
```

So my question is how is the variable being reassigned if there aren't any new declarations. I'm starting to think it has something to do with the for loops using for...of?

Comment: Maybe wrap all your code in a block `{}` if you want to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @skara9 That worked, thank you. So I'm guessing I have a conflict with a 3rd party?

Comment: Seems that way, check your script tags.

Answer (score 0):

An iteration variable `collectionSelector` is declared in the first loop, and then in the loop inside the event listener you declare the iterator the same way, bbut the second loop shares the scope of the first one, just change the name in the second loop

```js
for (const item of collectionSelectors) {
    item.classList.remove('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `collectionSelector` variable two times In `for loop`

```js
for (let collectionSelector of collectionSelectors) {// fist time
    let blockId = collectionSelector.dataset.blockId;

    let collectionCarousel = document.querySelector(`${sectionSelector} .recommendations__collection[data-block-id="${blockId}"]`);
    let otherCarousels = document.querySelectorAll(`${sectionSelector} .recommendations__collection:not([data-block-id="${blockId}"])`);

    collectionSelector.addEventListener('click', () => {

      for (let otherCarousel of otherCarousels) {
        otherCarousel.classList.remove('active');
      }

      for (let collectionSelector of collectionSelectors) { // 2nd time
        collectionSelector.classList.remove('active');
      }

      collectionSelector.classList.add('active');
      collectionCarousel.classList.add('active');

      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    })
  }
```

I the first `for loop` scope there is already a variable called `collectionSelector`, that's why there is an error. Change that to some another variable name, error should be fixed.